# Incorrect IP Locality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ip

I am developing an application which needs to track user locality based on their IP Address.

I'm using .NET's HttpRequestBase and from here I am extracting the UserAgent property & the UserHost property.

So from here I can actually get the user's IP address..but it gets a bit "weird" in certain situations.

Weird in the sense that, I'm getting incorrect IP information.

I am using http://ip-api.com/ and from their end it, I figure it's just a DB with a bunch of IPs listed.

E.g. if one of my users is sitting right next to me (mind you I'm based in FJ at the moment) and they open an email on their device it will state it's being opened in the UK. Mind you this occurs on ALOT of emails. Some emails maybe shown as opened in Texas, some in England and some in Springfield, IL.

The application I am developing requires downloading of a web-beacon (hence I needed IP locality).

Is this something that maybe due to a proxy being used to download the images? I know Gmail implements this their "Gmail Proxy".

Is there a rock solid way to find the user's IP?

Comment: rock solid way? **NO**

Comment: Write a link in the email "Click here so we get to know your IP". Add the legal text telling them what are you interested in getting their IP for and which parties will you share that information with.

Comment: Do you know a reason why their server's UserAgent is retrieving that? @SJuan76